# Image color search?

Tags: image, search, colors

I will create a search function for images based on colors.

At the moment, i have a function, which do the following things:

- resize a image to 50x50 pixel
- take a list of defined colors (for example red, it could have many sub color values like rgb(255,0,0),rgb(192,10,10) etc)
- now i go pixel per pixel through the image and check, which color of my list is the nearest.
- for example  a dark value of red, also is there one pixel in red in the image
- this i count and if there other red pixels in the rest of the image, i count it
- now i store for every country the values(counts) in the db.
- with this data, i can now create a sqql search and find out the images with red, sorted by the count

I have a table with colors (id, key (red),r,g,b)
And a table with image_id and key (image_id,key)

this works more or less good (i don't know if there is a better way available to detect colors)

But my other problam is now,   it are over 250.000 images, and the colors which can search can change everytime.

For example, if now a customer don't like to wish search for red, he will search for orange,
and orange is not in my list,  i can add this, but i must 
scann all 250.000 images again for this color.

Now my question. is there a good way to store the colors in a good compressed and
later re-useable for calculation in the db? Without 100 of megabytes.

Or did someone here know a really better way to provide a image color search function?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: can you save only main colors instead of counts for each image? like green, red, blue, yellow, or you need to save all tones? Edit: instead of detecting only RGB, try do index each image and detect top 10, 20 colors (which you need and save if it exit or not in image) from list for example?

Comment: The possible colors to search should be flexible.

Comment: And the customers can choose your wished colors himself in his admin menu. Some has red,green,yellow. Some has pink,orange,brown. If i calculate the top colors, for example i have a image with clouds,   I resize it to 10x10 Pixels. If i now calculate the top colors, i will get many white color values and blue values. For example a darker blue and lighter blue. But this both colors could be in my definiation of "blue" the same. I don't know if this is good?

Comment: If in the original Sky image for example a smart red ballon in the air,  the calculation can not see it in the 10x10 pixel image. Or is there a better way? What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

So you don't know colors, that customers will use? Because it would be simple.

1. You extract top 10 (more or less) most used colors in each image, aka "decrease color depth" and save these colors.
2. When customer do search, search in these colors table, of course there will not be exact match, like red == #ff0000, but you can define how close or far color is to what customer asked. For example red should match #980a14.
3. For really fast search you can add another cache table that has info if most used for humans colors exits in that image (like, red, blue, green, yellow, white, black).

So if you have lots of images, search by red or green will be really fast, almost instant.

So why we created top10 colors list? If user will search for some rare color like CornflowerBlue (#6495ED) you will need to think what to do then, get all top 10 colors for each 250k images (total 2.5kk o_O). It will be slow, but only 1 time, if you save these results in #3 mentioned table. So next time user search it, he get instant response.